# How many evaluations do you need to prove that a multivariate polynomial is the zero polynomial?

Tags: lagrange-interpolation, multivariate-polynomial

For a univariate polynomial $f$, you just need to prove that $f(x) = 0$ for $d+1$ distinct $x$ to prove that $f$ is the zero polynomial.

But for multivariate polynomials, how does that work? How many evaluations do you need to fully describe a multivariate polynomial?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving a multivariate polynomial is zero in $N$ easy steps. But what is $N$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3759389/proving-a-multivariate-polynomial-is-zero-in-n-easy-steps-but-what-is-n)